# ¿Cómo puedo implementar el cálculo de una potencia en jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones, bucle-for, bucles

¡Hola! El siguiente código por desgracia no me da el resultado correcto para 2 elevado a la 6 o ningún parámetro en este caso. Al verlo me parece que se debe porque no estoy multiplicando la base n veces dadas, sino que le pido al programa incrementar de 2 hasta 6. En tal caso, ¿cómo puedo indicarle que quiero el producto de la base n veces?

```
function calcularPotencia(base, exponente){
    for(i = base; i <= exponente; i++){
        let calculo = base * i;
        console.log(calculo);
    }
}
calcularPotencia(2, 6);
```

Comment: Una de dos: o haces el ciclo for y multiplicas la base **con ella misma** un número de veces igual a exponente (potencia es multiplicar la base el número de veces del exponente: `base*base*base*base*base*base`), o usas la sintaxis que te recomiendan en la respuesta y calculas de una vez, sin ciclos.

Comment: Hmm, entonces te refieres a que haga ¿calculo = base * base y el incremento ya estaría definido por el i++?  O ¿es otra la manera de plantearlo?

Comment: ¿Qué es la potencia de un número? Se supone que 10^3 es 10*10*10. La base se multiplica *por si misma* un número de veces dado por el exponente. Tu código hacía 10*3*3*3, que no es correcto. Entonces, o usabas el ciclo para multiplicar la base n veces, o usabas la notación en la respuesta para hacerlo SIN EL CICLO FOR. Como moraleja, siempre hay que resolver el problema antes de escribir el código :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Debes declarar la variable **`calculo`** en el contexto de la función
- Dentro del ciclo igualas a **`calculo`** con la operación que debe ser **`base ** potencia`** ( una sintaxis *reciente* en una de las versiones de EcmaScript)
- Fuera del contexto del for retornas a cálculo

Así

```
function calcularPotencia(base, exponente){
let calculo = 0
    for(i = base; i <= exponente; i++){
        calculo = base ** i;
       // console.log(calculo);
    }
return calculo
}
console.log(calcularPotencia(2, 6))
```

Por otro lado dado el contexto de tu ejercicio yo veo el ciclo for completamente de más.

Entonces si ya recibes dos números como argumentos basta operarlos por dentro con la misma sintaxis mencionada

Asi

```
function calcularPotencia(base, exponente){
    let calculo = base ** exponente;
    return calculo
}
console.log(calcularPotencia(2, 6))
```

Comment: ¡Muchímas gracias! Lo implementé, aunque tengo una duda. Al probar con solamente un símbolo de " * " me daba como respuesta 12, pero al poner " ** " me muestra el resultado correcto. Perdón mi ignorancia, pero como soy principiante, ¿será posible que me expliques cuando se utiliza el doble aterisco?

Comment: El doble asterisco es un sugar sintax de math.pow para cálculo de potencias

Comment: Ah, ya veo que editaste tu respuesta, pero aún así, solamente un asterisco ¿ya no es válido para esta situación?

Comment: Ya veo, ¡gracias!

Comment: Revisa la edición que hice al final

Comment: Estaba como enredada la respuesta sin la edición :)

Comment: si @Alfabravo de momento me concentré en la posible solución, pero luego dije ummmmm igual y si cambiamos esto y removemos el otro queda :)